# Thymeleaf is not working reading enum values from a object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to load a form with an object that has a enum property, seems that everything is working correctly, but when I try to apply a class I get an error. I can see in the HTML code that **checked** property is been apply correctly, however I need to apply an specific class to the checked element and in the following line is the one that I have the problem.

```
th:classappend="${'__${currency}__' == '__${reference.currency}__' ? 'active'}"
```

The complete element looks like this

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label th:each="currency : ${T(entity.CurrencyEnum).values()}"
    th:for="${#ids.next('currency')}" class="btn btn-default" th:classappend="${'__${currency}__' == '__${reference.currency}__' ? 'active'}">
        <input type="radio" th:name="currency" th:field="*{currency}"
        th:text="${currency}" th:value="${currency}" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance...

**--- UPDATE ---**

Here is a sample code after solving the issue. The problem was where I place the final ***}*** please be carefull with this detail.

```
<div th:fragment="currency (selected)">
    <label
        th:each="currency : ${T(CurrencyEnum).values()}"
        th:for="${#ids.next('currency')}" class="btn btn-default"
        th:classappend="${currency == selected} ? 'active'"> <input type="radio"
        th:name="currency" th:field="*{currency}" th:text="${currency}" th:value="${currency}" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `reference` is a variable defined somewhere and it is visible in this contex, you can try with this:

```
th:classappend="${currency} eq ${reference.currency} ? 'active'"
```